# Doctrine group data

Tags: sql, symfony, group-by, doctrine, dql

I would like to group doctrine data using the most performatic way. In this following query I need to create an object (or array) that returns the following SiteBundle:DJ with their childs SiteBundle:HJ followed by WHERE filters correctly. I am not sure if I need to use sub-query or group by clause, but I am using the following query:

```
$sql = ' SELECT dj FROM SiteBundle:DJ dj '
        . ' LEFT JOIN SiteBundle:HJ hj WITH dj.id = hj.date '
        . ' LEFT JOIN SiteBundle:Job job WITH job.id = dj.job '
        . ' LEFT JOIN SiteBundle:Dia d WITH d.id = dj.dia '
        . ' WHERE job.active = 1 and job.id = :job '
        . ' AND (hj.hour BETWEEN :ini and :fim) AND (d.data >= :now)'
        . ' GROUP BY dj.id, hj.id, d.data ORDER BY d.data ASC';
```

Returns:

```
array:2 [▼
   0 => DJ {#1584 ▶}
   1 => DJ {#1580 ▶}
]
```

$dj->getHJ() returns all the SiteBundle:HJ related to this DJ, but I need only the ones I've filtered in where clause.

How to group them?

Comment: Better use a repository-method to perform the custom-query. Then get the entity collection from the repository like `$repository->getDJsBookedBetweenDates(DateTimeImmutable $from, DateTimeImmutable $to)` when you need them ... i.e. in a controller-action. Don't bloat your entities with such complex query-logic or endless chains of criteria. Just my few cents.

Comment: Sorry, that is not a solution. This code is inside repository, but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what you expected to happen is actually a bad idea in the global context.

doctrine is first and foremost about correctness. even though you filter something in your query (and don't select it), doctrine will provide the full collection when you (essentially) call `$object->getCollection()` because **it's the correct collection for that object**. queries of the past don't really matter here.

However, the persistent collection you usually get from doctrine for relations can be filtered: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/collection-criteria
(however, your filter might not be representable by the options it provides)

or you filter the collection manually, i.e. write a new function for that entity that returns a filtered collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ";" at the end of the where clause, remove it and re-try.